# Strange error: formal arguments omitted in the method definition cannot be in the signature

Tags: r, r-s4

I am trying to define generic methods in one R file and implement them in another R file.
But I get an error which I don't understand.

**Questions:**

1. What is the source of the error?
2. How do I fix the error?

Contents of `BuyProbabilityGeneric.R`:

```
setGeneric("FirstTimeBuyProbability",
        valueClass = "numeric",
        function(object, period, price) {
    standardGeneric("FirstTimeBuyProbability")
})

setGeneric("ReturningBuyProbability",
        valueClass = "numeric",
        function(object, period1, price1, period2, price2) {
    standardGeneric("ReturningBuyProbability")
})
```

Contents of `BuyProbabilityBasic.R`:

```
setClass("BuyProbabilityBasic", representation(
        full.price.probability = "numeric",
        elasticity = "numeric"))

setMethod("FirstTimeBuyProbability",
        signature(object = "BuyProbabilityBasic", 
                period = "numeric", price = "numeric"), 
        function(object, t, price) {
    full.price.probability * price^elasticity
})

setMethod("ReturningBuyProbability",
        signature(object = "BuyProbabilityBasic", 
                period1 = "numeric", price1 = "numeric",
                period2 = "numeric", price2 = "numeric"), 
        function(object, period1, price1, period2, price2) {
    max(0, FirstTimeBuyProbability(object, period2, price2) -
        FirstTimeBuyProbability(object, period1, price1))
})
```

R console output:

```
> source('BuyProbabilityGeneric.R')
> source('BuyProbabilityBasic.R')
Error in conformMethod(signature, mnames, fnames, f, fdef, definition) : 
  in method for ‘FirstTimeBuyProbability’ with signature 
‘object="BuyProbabilityBasic",period="numeric",price="numeric"’: 
formal arguments (period = "numeric") omitted in the method definition
cannot be in the signature
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
setMethod("FirstTimeBuyProbability",
          signature(object = "BuyProbabilityBasic", 
                    period = "numeric", price = "numeric"), 
          function(object, period, price) {
            full.price.probability * price^elasticity
          })
```

Notice how I changed `t` to `period` in your function definition formals.  Basically, you were trying to define a function where the formals conflicted with the signature.

Comment: I can't believe that I missed this error which was right under my nose. Thanks!

Comment: @ILiketoCode, sometimes the longer you look the harder it becomes to see.  Happens to me all the time.

Comment: I can relate to this as well. Just spent almost an hour looking at my code until I discovered my generic had an argument called "alfa" and the offending method had it spelled "alpha". Perhaps the error message could be clearer.

Comment: Watch out for alfalfa